# Кто такой царь Горох?

Tags: фразеология

Когда хотят сказать о чем-то, что это было очень давно, говорят "это было при царе Горохе". А интересно было бы узнать, кто такой этот царь Горох?
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://frazbook.ru/2008/10/22/gorox-pri-care-goroxe/

«При царе Горохе» – это выражение, употребляемое в значении: очень давно, в незапамятную старину, «когда царь Горох с грибами воевал». Одна из русских сказок начинается так: «В то давнее время, когда мир божий наполнен был лешими, ведьмами да русалками, когда реки текли молочные, берега были кисельные, а по полям летали жареные куропатки, в то время жил-был царь, по имени Горох» (Народные русские сказки А.Н. Афанасьева). И.Е. Тимошенко, замечая, что происхождение поговорки о царе Горохе загадочно, высказывает предположение: не является ли она переделкой очень распространенной греческой поговорки, употреблявшейся также для обозначения глубокой старины, именно: «пресбютерос (или архаитерос) Кодру», – то есть, «более старший (или более древний), чем Кодр» (мифический царь Аттики). «Не переделал ли какой-нибудь грамотей, – пишет исследователь, – имени Кодрос на Горох, передавая греческое выражение по-русски и руководясь при этом лишь некоторым созвучием: Ко[д]ро – Горо ... Необходимо, впрочем, отметить разницу в тоне: грек относился к имени своего последнего царя с полным уважением, чуть не благоговением, и употреблял свою пословицу вполне искренне; мы же произносим имя нашего мифического царя иронически, с полным недоверием ко всему, что происходило в его правление».

http://esperanto-plus.ru/carj-goroh.htm - интересное стихотворение